# How to solve using Locks?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I came across this question asked to a friend in interviews. I tried using Synchronized method/block but that doesn't fully satisfy all the use cases mentioned in the question, can someone please help me with how to solve this question using Locks ?

Given class structures with following functions:

```
Class Client:
    init();
    request();
    close();

Class ClientWrapper(Client):
    init();
    request();
    close();
```

Here, class **Client** is like an abstract class that deals with responsibilities like initialising connection to the server using init(), request() is used to make request to the server and close() is used to close the connection to the server.

**Question:** Multiple threads can concurrently access methods of class **ClientWrapper**. One needs to implement all the methods of  class **ClientWrapper** such that following use cases are covered -

- If init() is in progress by some thread, then block other concurrent threads to execute request() or close() method
- Do not allow concurrent calls to init() method.
- Allow concurrent calls to request() method if init() is already called successfully.
- If some thread is still using request(), then block any other thread to close the connection using close() method
- Once connection is closed, do not allow subsequent calls to close() method
- Do not allow concurrent calls to close() method
- ...etc.

Thanks!!

Comment: Please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822)

Comment: @tgdavies This is not a homework question. It was asked in one of the interviews and I have less experience in using Locks, that's why seeking help on how to tackle this question using Locks.

Comment: Then, the difference between a homework question and an interview question is tiny. Besides that, the description is unclear. What does “do not allow subsequent calls to close() method” imply? Ignore them? Throw an exception? Reverse time and make them never happen? And what about subsequent calls to the init() method after the first completed?

Comment: You stated that you think that you can achieve this with Locks, but have you read any of the documentation on Locks? Have you searched for some examples using Locks? As @Holger argues, there is little difference between a homework question and an interview question, so tgdavies' link is definitely worth a read.